# Update Product Stock and Price by uploading CSV using Command Line

Tags: magento2, csv, command-line, import-products

I am updating products stock and price by uploading CSV in adminform magento2.

[image]

I want to perform the same thing using command line.
Is it Possible ?
How ?

Answer (score 0):

As per me,
It's not possible in Default Magento.

Still you can programmatically import through custom script.